# How do i get a specific line from an output using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the code below that returns the hostname and IP address of a given server. How can i only have the hostname as the output?

```
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "skip=3 delims=: tokens=2 usebackq" %%j in (`nslookup %%i`) do @echo %%j >> Devices_With_IP.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your machine uses English:

```
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%j in (
  'nslookup %%i ^| find "Name:"'
) do @echo %%j >> Devices_With_IP.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `findstr` command on the output of your `nslookup` to get only the line containing "Name".

```
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims=: " %%j in (`nslookup %%i ^| findstr Name`) do @echo %%j >> Devices_With_IP.txt
```

Note that I also rearranged the `/F` conditions in the second loop in order to include space as a deliminator, this removes the leading spaces before the output.

Using the `find` command instead of `findstr` -

```
FOR /F %%i in (servers.txt) do FOR /F "tokens=2 usebackq delims=: " %%j in (`nslookup %%i ^| find "Name"`) do @echo %%j >> Devices_With_IP.txt
```

Just realized that using find instead of findstr makes this (almost) exactly the same as dbenham's answer.

Comment: No output is generated.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, I just added the redirect to your `Devices_With_IP.txt`, before it only outputted to the terminal. Was that the problem?

Comment: Nope. I had it as well. No results are displayed nor is a file generated.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey it works for me. What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7. I do have access to the findstr command. Ran it against the `dir` command and it works just fine.